# MySQL search very slow, bad query or indexes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

We have a table in an application, which is VASTLY HUGE. Easily millions of rows.

The structure is basically as follows:

```
SERIES_ID | YEAR | DAY_SINCE_EPOCH | HOUR | MINUTE | VALUE
```

We have indexes on YEAR and DAY_SINCE_EPOCH.

The problem is that certain kind of queries are very slow, such as:

```
SELECT
 ...
WHERE
   SERIES_ID = 3 AND
   DAY_SINCE_EPOCH < 16000 AND
   YEAR = 2012
ORDER BY 
   DAY_SINCE_EPOCH DESC,
   HOUR DESC,
   MINUTE DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This takes about 10 seconds in a table with 2M rows, and well over 20 seconds in a table with 18M rows.

The intent is to find the last record of series 3, before day 16000. The YEAR=2012 is there to speed up the lookup.

So I was wondering, do we have the indexes set up right? Perhaps it'd be faster without the year index? Or with added SERIES_ID index or something like that?

Or just restructuring the query would help?

*Any idea how to speed up the search will be welcome!*

Comment: try a composite index on `(series_id,year,days_since_epoch)`

Comment: Have you JOIN(s) in your query?

Comment: Nope, it's just a plain table, no join, no foreign keys or stuff like that. I think I'll give a try to the multi-column index.

Comment: Checking the simple stuff as well, I'm assuming these fields are of type INT?

Comment: What are your server ? And have you allocated enough memory to your MySQL server (my.ini file) ?

Comment: @MLeFevre yes, they are INT, of the right lengths (INT(2) for mins, for example)

Comment: @kmas There's a lot of fields, which one to look for? (Btw I've not set up the server, so I'm seeing this conf file fir the first time now)

Comment: @MightyPork Unrelated to this question then, but you might find useful anyway. For stuff like mins (I assume you mean minutes, so its max value would be 60) you could use TINYINT(2) instead, [save yourself some disk space](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: The index on multiple columns can help you. But I'm pretty sure a better my.ini configuration would help you too. Execute `EXPLAIN` followed by your query and post the result.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the EXPLAIN after myadmin lets me. Now the CREATE INDEX is hogging it.

Comment: If I remember well, the default configuration of MySQL is not for large databases (more than 10 millions rows).

Comment: @kmas if you wouldn't mind, please look yourself and advise what to change: my.cfg - http://pastebin.com/H5CQkCcH

Comment: Is your database MyISAM or innodb ?

Comment: I believe it's MyISAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This index might help:

```
> create index on your_table(series_id, day_since_epoch, year);
```

Comment: wow, this index totally turned snail into a cheetah! Thanks a bunch, Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

Check these conditions

```
SERIES_ID = 3 AND
DAY_SINCE_EPOCH < 16000 AND
YEAR = 2012
```

when you are updating the table(eg. saving new records) then save the true/false info on a "bit" column then check for it just like

```
where checked=1 .....

 SERIES_ID | YEAR | DAY_SINCE_EPOCH | HOUR | MINUTE | VALUE | checked
```

Comment: As if the query's WHERE clause will always remain same? 3 and 16000 and 2012?

Comment: There is an interactive view for finding things in the table, rendering a chart of a week's values etc. This would not help.

Comment: Then a scheduled (once per hour) updater could solve?